# Trying to understand USB and Thunderbolt maximum transfer rates

Tags: data-transfer, hardware-acceleration

If a USB port can transfer data at 10GB/s and a Thunderbolt at 20 GB/s, then how is this speed achieved when say an average hard drive only has an average speed of 100 MB/s?

Comment: It’s not achieved. The transfer limits are determined by the device.

Comment: SATA has long since been “faster than mechanical hard drives”.

Comment: I have a SATA HD 5200 rpm.  I've read that it has an average speed of 100 MB/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this speed achieved when say an average hard drive only has an average speed of 100 MB/s?

It isn't... these speeds indicate the theoretical maximum bandwidth available.

Don't forget that to/from storage aren't the only places that you send data... if you're using Thunderbolt to drive a display, then a standard 1080p60 display will take approx 2.8Gb/s... a 4k 60Hz display will require about 11.1Gb/s.

---

An analogy could be a PC power supply that *can* supply 600W... it doesn't somehow force 600W into your computer all the time, but it is able to provide that much power if the computer tries to draw it... or a car that *can* go super fast.

A couple of other things worth pointing out:

- Big 'B' indicates **bytes** (8x bits) - MB (Megabytes) and GB (Gigabytes) are typically used when discussing storage capacities (e.g: Hard Disk / SSD / Memory Card / RAM)
- Little 'b' indicates **bits** - Mb (Megabits) and Gb (Gigabits) are typically used when discussing link throughput / bandwidth figures (e.g: SATA / PCIe / USB / Thunderbolt / xDSL / DOCSIS)

It's also worth pointing out that while Thunderbolt 2 claims 20Gb/s, Thunderbolt 3 can actually push up to 40Gb/s